# subprocess call in python, getting error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, interface, subprocess

```
import subprocess 
import optparse 

def ChangeMac(interface, new_mac):
    print("mac changed")

    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

parser =optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC address")
parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="new MAC address")

(options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()

interface = options.interface
new_mac = options.new_mac

ChangeMac(optoins.interface, options.new_mac)
```

I am trying to call the function ChangeMac by giving it the variables of interface and new_mac.
Although i am getting an error that the second parameter is not a string. Although the user should be first asked what value they want to be entered before the function is even called.

Comment: Typo in the code: ChangeMac(optoins.interface, options.new_mac)   should be   ChangeMac(options.interface, options.new_mac)

Comment: sorry, i was running this code in a virtual machine so i could not copy and paste over. So sorry for any spelling mistakes in this version.

Comment: Are you calling the script with parameters? This works for me:  `python macchange.py --interface=111 --mac=222`

Comment: ok ok i am a fool, thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Question is resolved, I needed to add parameters before executing the file. Pretty new to subproccess.

Example : python3 mac_changer.py -i eth0 -m 00:11:22:33:44:55:66